# A function in Javascript that will sleep for specified amount of time? (setInterval doesn't work like I want it to)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
console.log("Line at the start");
sleepFunction(5000);
console.log("Line printed after 5 seconds");
```

Output:

```
Line at the start
<waits for 5 seconds>
Line printed after 5 seconds
```

Is there any function like this? I've tried to use setInterval but the line printed after 5 seconds appears first, then it waits for 5 seconds.

Comment: No. Asynchronous approaches to things like this are the norm in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments you can use asynchronous code

```
function sleep(msec) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msec))
}

async function print() {
    console.log("Line at the start")
    await sleep(5000);
    console.log("Line printed after 5 seconds")
}

print();
```

Or use only setTimeout and print the second line in the callback that gets invoked after 5 seconds

```
function print2() {
    console.log("Line at the start2")
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Line printed after 5 seconds2")
    }, 5000)
}

print2()
```